# What, if anything, can I do to fix this treadmill?

Tags: repair, appliances

A 10s video of my loud, squeaky treadmill operating is shown [here](https://youtu.be/FGrBI3-o3mM).

As the video shows, it squeaks and makes a grinding sound, and it is much louder when a person is running on it. I have to wear earplugs to use it.

I bought it new only a year ago, the model is '[Sole F63 Treadmill](https://www.soletreadmills.com/Treadmills/F63-SOLE-Treadmill)'.

Any ideas on what I might try to fix it? It was a huge pain to put together but I would be willing to take it apart and try to fix since these things are expensive and I cannot buy another. Do you think a manageable fix might be possible, e.g. by oiling something in there or maybe replacing some bearing?

Comment: Stop using it until it gets fixed.  For instance, it could be a bad bearing and replacing a $5 part would fix it, but if its used with a bad bearing for a while, the axels or the hole the bearing presses into could be damaged which would be a much more involved and expensive fix.

Answer (score 4):

You bought it new a year ago, and the manufacturer appears to have a decent warranty. Contact them. Any "taking it apart to fix it" is likely to interfere with the proper warranty process.

For reference, it's probably something wrong with the motor; you can confirm by using a cardboard tube or the like to focus on specific areas of the treadmill.

Comment: Yes, their warranty is better than most. They came out and replaced parts on mine, even though the problem would not repeat while the tech was at my house.